# R extrafont not using fonts on Ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu, fonts

I am running an Ubuntu AWS instance and am having trouble loading my fonts in my R plots.  I am using the `extrafont` package and have read many different StackOverflow posts on this, but I still cannot get this working.

The font I want has family = "Libre Baskerville" and is in my /home/ubuntu/.fonts directory.  There are 3 .ttf files there (one for regular, italic, and bold).

Using the `extrafont` package I have installed these fonts using `font_import(paths = "/home/ubuntu/.fonts/", pattern = ".*")`  This seems to have run successfully.

And I also used `loadfonts()` to ensure this family is loaded into my session.  When I use `names(pdfFonts())` the output includes "Libre Baskerville" among the names.

In addition when I use the `fonts()` command I get `[1] "Libre Baskerville"` as the only output.

When I use the `fonttable()` command I get an output of 3 rows, one for the regular font, one for the bold font, and one for the italic font, all with the FamilyName of "Libre Baskerville".

As far as I know everything looks how it should for these fonts to be working properly.  However, when I call this font family, the font does not show up as Libre Baskerville but something else (I think Helvetica).

For example, a simple ggplot does not produce the font I want:

`ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = wt, y= mpg)) + geom_text(label = mtcars$cyl, family = "Libre Baskerville")`

Does anyone have any ideas what I could be doing incorrectly here?

EDIT:  To get this to work on my Windows computer I had to use this command `windowsFonts(my_font=windowsFont("Libre Baskerville"))`.  However, I am trying to transition to AWS and Ubuntu so I have had to change my approach.

Comment: The equivalent of windowsFonts on Linux would be `x11Fonts`

Comment: I tried this using `X11Font("Libre Baskerville")` but this fails because you need to give it an X11 mapping, but unfortunately I am not sure how to map this font to something that X11 can understand.  Do you have any ideas on this front?

Comment: Perhaps you should review the material in the `pdf` and `postscript` help pages. In particular the  link at the bottom of `postscript`: https://www.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2006-2.pdf . I really cannot do any testing because you have not provided enough detail to duplicate your situation. The `?X11Fonts` help page says there are two different font selection mechanisms.